# Why only some child elements will have their properties defined by their parents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datacontext

```
<Window x:Class="tests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Red" Foreground="Cyan">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button>123</Button>
        <TextBlock>123</TextBlock>
        <TextBox>123</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In the above code, only the TextBlock will "inherit" both the foreground and background colors. Shouldn't the Button and TextBox have those colors too? Why don't they have it?
[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8014/5uslgmbzkbyurgwuwgqtzv2.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8014/5uslgmbzkbyurgwuwgqtzv2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Button` specially opted out of `Background` value inheritance, in order to have consistent look. See [en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts—Property_Value_Inheritance](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Property_Value_Inheritance) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button background="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel1,Path=Background}" .../>
```